# CDialog::Create fails for dialog with ActiveX control

Tags: mfc, cdialog, com-server

I have a module that creates a modeless dialog containing an ActiveX control. This module was part of an MFC EXE application and the creation of the dialog worked fine. Recently, I moved the module out into an ATL/COM server and copied the dialog resource from the EXE into the COM server. When trying to create the modeless dialog using `CDialog::Create()` an error happens.

I debugged into `CDialog::Create` and noticed that it fails in `::CreateDialogIndirect()` which returns `NULL` and `GetLastError` returns `0`. I changed the "No Fail Create" flag to True in the dialog resource properties and I get more details into the error. The problem happens in the dialog's `DoDataExchange()` within the `DDX_Control` macro. This calls into the `CDataExchange::PrepareCtrl()` with the control's resource ID as follows:

```
HWND CDataExchange::PrepareCtrl(int nIDC)
{
   ASSERT(nIDC != 0);
   ASSERT(nIDC != -1); // not allowed
   HWND hWndCtrl;
   COleControlSite* pSite = NULL;
   m_pDlgWnd->GetDlgItem(nIDC, &hWndCtrl);
   if (hWndCtrl == NULL)
   {
      // Could be a windowless OCX
      pSite = m_pDlgWnd->GetOleControlSite(nIDC);
      if (pSite == NULL)
      {
         TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Error: no data exchange control with ID 0x%04X.\n", nIDC);
         ASSERT(FALSE);
         AfxThrowNotSupportedException();
      }
   }
   m_idLastControl = nIDC;
   m_bEditLastControl = FALSE; // not an edit item by default

   return hWndCtrl;
}
```

The call to the function `m_pDlgWnd->GetOleControlSite()` fails for the resource ID passed. By the way, the resource ID is the control's ID.

Any suggestions on why this works inside the EXE and fails in the COM server?

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem.  In my case the problem turned out to be that I hadn't called AfxEnableControlContainer().  I added a call to that in my app's InitInstance member function and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem just the other day. Copied a control from one dialog resource to another. As it happened, you can't just copy an ActiveX control from one dialog to another the way you do with other MFC controls. For an ActiveX control the rc file contains a DLGINIT section. For example I have a form with an IE WebBrowser control:

```
IDD_ONLINE_REPORTVIEW_FORM DIALOGEX 0, 0, 320, 200
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_CONTROL | WS_CHILD
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_EXPLORER1,"{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}",WS_TABSTOP,7,61,299,77
END
```

and below in the rc file, there is a DLGINIT section:

```
IDD_ONLINE_REPORTVIEW_FORM DLGINIT
BEGIN
    IDC_EXPLORER1, 0x376, 160, 0
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x004c, 0x0000, 0x2e68, 0x0000, 0x0ceb, 0x0000, 0x0000, 
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x004c, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0001, 
0x0000, 0xd0e0, 0x0057, 0x3573, 0x11cf, 0x69ae, 0x0008, 0x2e2b, 0x6212, 
0x0008, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x004c, 0x0000, 0x1401, 0x0002, 0x0000, 
0x0000, 0x00c0, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x4600, 0x0080, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0000, 
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 
    0
END
```

Open the rc file's source and search for your control ID. Search for DLGINIT section and copy it to your new dialog

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I put a wrong Dialog ID while calling

```
BOOL Create(UINT nID, CWnd * pWnd);
```

so failed on `DoDataExchange()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another situation where one can get the same Debug Assersion Warnings(Error: no data exchange control with ID dlgdata:line 40):

e.g. if you create a dialog instance of CDialogExExample by virtual function CDialogExExample::Create(CONTROL_ID, ..), while the CONTROL_ID is inconstant with the IDD_EXAMPLE(enum{ IDD = IDD_EXAMPLE};) in CDialogExExample header file....then one could add control fails always.

Here's [an inspiring link from msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6daa194-e7f1-4f05-be59-93164d15e895/dialogex-inherited-error-error-no-data-exchange-control-with-id?forum=vcmfcatl) !

may be helpful to somebody:)

PS:this situation maybe same with @Hank Chang's answer

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a MFC dialog which hosts .Net UI control through ActiveX.

Upon debugging i found, DoModal failed and returned -1 and GetLastError gave 0.

After a day of debugging, it turned out to be .Net Assemblies version mismatch issue. This lead to  OLE control instantiation failure.

WinDBG excerpt:

> (21b0.71cc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
>   CoCreateInstance of OLE control {EE3C4329-83A8-4DD8-A74C-680AC01AC593}
>   failed.
>
> > > > Result code: 0x80131040

HRESULT value 0x80131040 meaning :

**The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.**

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found after having that exact error was to check the class definition in the header file.
Assuming the class is

Then in the following code

```
class CNewDlg : public CMyBaseDlg
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CNewDlg)
public:
    CNewDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~CNewDlg();

    // Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_MYNEWDIALOGID };
```

check the line:

```
enum { IDD = IDD_MYNEWDIALOGID };
```

making sure you have the correct ID. The error you are getting might be a result of copying and pasting code from another header file of a previously created control / dialog without updating this ID.

That should match the definition of the dialog in your .rc file. For example:

```
IDD_MYNEWDIALOGID DIALOGEX 0, 0, 445, 314
```

Comment: This cannot be the issue. As explained in the OP, the dialog *does* get created (providing appropriate flags), so the `IDD` enum is correct. The issue is with creating the ActiveX control.

Comment: Dialogs in MFC are created in 2 steps. MFC first constructs the native dialog, passing in the dialog's resource ID. When that succeeds, it subclasses the native controls with MFC class instances (that's implemented in `DDX_Control`). The OP has verified, that the first step succeeds, so they are certainly passing in the correct dialog ID. The fact that passing in the wrong ID exhibits the same error doesn't make this an answer to the question. This is an answer to a different question.

Comment: I posted my answer based on experience. There could be many reasons for the error described in the OP and the solution I posted worked for me. I  suggest to allow @user1756114 to comment if my solution worked for him as well.